# Python "setuptools" build with C++ files in higher directory

Tags: python, setuptools, pybind11

I am struggling to compile an extension module.

My C++ files are in a higher directory than my "setup.py"/etc. files.  This is because the Python extension is a binding of a C++ library, and so is hierarchically subordinate<sup>[1]</sup>.  This use-case, I should think, is basic and common.

I list my files using relative paths in my "setup.py" file.  A simplified + untested but representative example:

```py
from setuptools import setup
from pybind11.setup_helpers import Pybind11Extension
myfiles = [ "../src/functionality.cpp", "../src/pybind11_binding_main.cpp" ]
setup_args = dict(
    ext_modules = [
        Pybind11Extension( "myext", myfiles )
    ],
)
setup(**setup_args)
```

On Windows, "py -m build --wheel" in this directory this works just fine, producing a library that works.  However, with the equivalent command on Linux, I get:

```
Fatal error: can't create build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-311/../src/pybind11_binding_main.o: No such file or directory
```

This happens because apparently no one considered relative paths that go up, for example because of the use-case above.  The only useful reference to this problem is a [decade-old bug report](https://bugs.python.org/issue9023) that wasn't fixed.  The given workaround was to use absolute paths, which I interpret as the following:

```py
myfiles = [ "../src/functionality.cpp", "../src/pybind11_binding_main.cpp" ]
import os.path
myfiles = [ os.path.abspath(path) for path in myfiles ]
```

However, with modern <s>technology</s> versions of the tools, this produces the following error:

```
error: Error: setup script specifies an absolute path:

    /absolute/path/to/myproject/src/pybind11_binding_main.cpp

setup() arguments must *always* be /-separated paths relative to the
setup.py directory, *never* absolute paths.

ERROR Backend subprocess exited when trying to invoke build_wheel
```

The error is descriptive, sensible, and well-taken—but also maddeningly short-sighted in that *there apparently is no alternative*.

What am I *supposed* to do?  Do they just assume any project is to be configured wholly and solely as a Python project?  Can I do something like copy the C++ from the upper-level directory and the Python into some kind of temporary staging directory automatically?  This should not be so difficult or weird!

---

<sub><sub><sup>[1]</sup>As well as that Python will name the package whatever its folder is called, whereas I am using that folder name for something else at root namespace.  Also, as a practical issue, "python3 -m build" (apparently by unconfigurable *design*) spews a bunch of directories everywhere, and I'd rather not have that at my project root   :V</sub></sub>

Comment: Yeah, Python packages assume some root, as its tools cannot package files above that root (i.e. it is impossible to have a zip file that goes above `/`), and given a source distribution - think of the usability (also security) implications if one is able to extract a zip files _above_ the current working directory - this particular case is hairy enough that it makes sense to simply disallow it.  For your case, just have your Python setup at your project root, which is pretty much what all other projects do (or have them generate the relevant files inside the Python root, e.g. mv/cp/symlink).

Comment: Before you ask "but all I am doing is to build I am not packaging a source archive using Python tools" but those Python tools assume a consistent behavior across _all_ their supported use-case, which includes generating source archives.